# Highlight specific points in matplotlib scatterplot

Tags: python, pandas, csv, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I have a CSV with 12 columns of data. [I'm focusing on these 4 columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FGZE.png)

Right now I've plotted "Pass def" and "Rush def". I want to be able to highlight specific points on the scatter plot. For example, I want to highlight 1995 DAL point on the plot and change that point to a color of yellow.

I've started with a for loop but I'm not sure where to go. Any help would be great.

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import csv
import random

df = pd.read_csv('teamdef.csv')

x = df["Pass Def."]
y = df["Rush Def."]
z = df["Season"]

points = []
for point in df["Season"]:
    if point == 2015.0:

    print(point)


plt.figure(figsize=(19,10))
plt.scatter(x,y,facecolors='black',alpha=.55, s=100)
plt.xlim(-.6,.55)
plt.ylim(-.4,.25)
plt.xlabel("Pass DVOA")
plt.ylabel("Rush DVOA")
plt.title("Pass v. Rush DVOA")
plot.show
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can layer multiple scatters, so the easiest way is probably

```py
plt.scatter(x,y,facecolors='black',alpha=.55, s=100)
plt.scatter(x, 2015.0, color="yellow")
```

Comment: ok. that makes sense. I'm getting this error though: ValueError: x and y must be the same size. I think it's recognizing 2015.0 as the y value

Comment: Yeah, sorry that was unclear. I meant you need to plot the x value that y value is at. So:
 `plt.scatter(df["Pass Def."][df['Season']== 2015.0], 2015.0, color="yellow")`